# When(why) to use step/pulse/ramp functions in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Hello guys I'd like to know the answer to the question that is the titled named by.

For example if I have physical system described in differential equation(s), how should I know when I should use step, pulse or ramp generator?

What exactly does it do? 
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Use those functions for what? What do your DEs have to do with simulink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are mostly the remnants of the classical control times. The main reason why they are so famous is because of their simple Laplace transform terms. `1,1/s` and `1/s^2`. Then you can multiply these with the plant and you would get the Laplace transform of the output.

Back in the day, what you only had was partial fraction expansion and Laplace transform tables to get an idea what the response would look like. And today, you can basically simulate whatever input you like. So they are not really neeeded which is the answer to your question.

But since people used these signals so often they have spotted certain properties. For example, step response is good for assessing the transients and the steady state tracking error value, ramp response is good for assessing (reference) following error (which introduces double integrators) and so on. Hence, some consider these signals as the characteristic functions though it is far from the truth. Especially, you should keep in mind that, just because the these responses are OK, the system is not necessarily stable.

However, keep in mind that these are extremely primitive ways of assessing the system. Currently, they are taught because they are good for giving homeworks and making people acquainted with Simulink etc.

Answer (score 0):

They are used to determine system characteristics. If you are studying a system of differential equations you would want to know different characteristics from the response of the system from these kinds of inputs since these inputs are the very fundamental ones. For example a system whose output blows up for a pulse input is unstable, and you would not want to have such a system in real life(except in rare situations). It's too difficult for me to explain it all in an answer, you should start with this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_analysis).